# Use wild card after equal sign in Google sheets - SUM IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

I m looking for solution how i can use wild card * in SUM IMPORTRANGE

For Example :

Searching by name :
John*
John Frank
Carsen John
John Oscar

and SUM of that ranges there values where John occurs

`=ArrayFormula(SUM( ( IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "Data1!A3:A")="John*")*IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "Data1!B3:B") ))`

Result No Found

If i use full name its working

`=ArrayFormula(SUM( ( IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "Data1!A3:A")="John Oscar")*IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "Data1!B3:B") ))`

Result : Found

so please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "Data1!A3:B"), 
 "select sum(Col2) where Col1 matches 'John.*' label sum(Col2)''")
```

[image]

note that its case sensitive

Comment: I tried but failed

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL1", "DATA1!$CR3:$CT"), 
 "select sum(Col98) where Col96 matches 'John*' label sum(Col98)''")


Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col98

Comment: @AliSaleem yes, thats right. you dont have column 98. CR = column 1, CS = column 2 and CT = column 3